# HERE - Cluster view all items in clusterprovider

Tags: here-api

after adding all items into a clustered data provider i would like to set the bounds of the map to make sure all items are displayed.

in case of a marker group this is easy by using the bounding box of the marker group but i cant figure out what to use with a clustered data provider

Comment: sharing some code of what you have tried so far makes it easier to help you.

Comment: it sure would but because i could not find a solution there is no code to share. 

here is a link to the clustering example. 

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/clustering/marker-clustering

after creating the cluster i would need to make sure all items are shown on the map. The example simply shows the map at a certain location with a specific zoom level

Answer (score 0):

H.clustering.ICluster contains method getBoundingBox() that could help to set the bounds of the map.

Reference can be taken from here :
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.17.0/api_reference/H.clustering.ICluster.html